# OLAP Solution for MySQL

Tags: mysql, olap, xmla

I'm developing a project on .NET and I need to include an OLAP-based reporting module.
What is the better OLAP solution for the large MySQL DB(each month there will be about 10 millions new rows), that supports XML for Analysis (XMLA)?

I've already tried icCube, MicroStrategy, Tableau and Mondrian. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: I don't think Tableau has an XMLA compliant server (you can connect to one).

Comment: Sure, it does not have the one.